# API certificate not trusted by browser, what can I do?

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I have a react web app up and running. It makes calls to my API but my API is running on my own machine. so the flow would be something like this.

[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) makes a call to (192.192.219.1) (Not actually my machines IP but you get the idea). The API is a Java spring boot API and it is able to send the data back to my react site. My API however is using a self assigned certificate. My issue is that the browser does not trust my self assigned certificate. How can I get the browser to trust my IP (where API is located)?

Comment: How Public web will reach to your own machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free Let´s encrypt certificate:

https://letsencrypt.org/

And here you have a let´s encrypt spring boot installation guide:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-secured-by-lets-encrypt

Comment: this wont work when other people use my site because when the site makes a call to my api , it will show up as not trusted

Comment: Sorry I though it was for local development. I edit my answer, you can use Let´s encrypt, it´s free and really easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), to route all (or part of) incoming traffic through an SSL/TLS encrypted route before ending up to your machine.

- You can get a domain name for 10$/year or even free (with limitations as far as ownership and flexibility goes), from any domain registrar. I personally like [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/). ([NOIP](https://www.noip.com/) for free domains)
- Sign up for Cloudflare's free plan, and add your domain as a web site (They have pretty clear and detailed documentation for everything you can do with their service).
- Then under `DNS` settings in Cloudflare's website manage page add an `A` type MX record with `name=www` and assign to it your API machine's IP address.
- Then back to Namecheap's admin page, under `Domain`/`DNS`/`Nameservers` change the default option to `Custom nameservers` and paste in the nameservers  Cloudflare provides you in your their DNS settings page.

It might take a few hours for the nameservers to update so that the traffic to your API routes through Cloudflare first, but once its done, you're set!

Under the `SSL/TLS` tab in Cloudflare's admin page, you can choose the exact configuration for traffic encryption for your machine.

[image: SSL/TLS configuration options in Cloudflare]

The minimum encryption mode for your needs is `Flexible` since the incoming requests will be going into a publicly trusted route, regardless what is going on between Cloudflare and you. Of course it would be best to configure your Cloudflare and your personal server to use `Full` encryption mode by installing an SSL certificate provided by Cloudflare and signed by [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com) if I am not mistaken. You can never be too safe IMO.

This is **just one way** to do this, there are probably better ways, but I like this and it works for me. More specific details for this whole setup and potential troubleshooting, can be found on Cloudflare's docs. this is just my personal guideline.